# Infinitary logic doesn't have (finite) Robinson property: a counterexample?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Given a standard definition of an abstract logic $\mathcal{L}_A$ (cfr. Barwise & Feferman, *Model-theoretic Logics*, Springer-Verlag, 1985), let $E_A(\sigma)$ be the class of $\mathcal{L}_A$-sentences for a signature $\sigma$. Two $\sigma$-structures are $\mathcal{L}_A$-equivalent iff they satisfy the same sentences in $E_A(\sigma)$.

The finite Robinson property is defined as follows: given two signatures $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$, for all $\varphi \in E_A(\sigma)$, $\varphi' \in E_A(\sigma')$ and $\Psi \subseteq E_A(\sigma \cap \sigma')$, if $\Psi \cup \{\varphi\}$ and $\Psi \cup \{\varphi'\}$ are both satisfiable and every two $(\sigma \cap \sigma')$-models of $\Psi$ are $\mathcal{L}_A$-equivalent, then $\Psi \cup \{\varphi, \varphi'\}$ is satisfiable.

Let $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$ the abstract logic obtained from first-order logic allowing countably-long disjunctions (hence also conjunctions). An exercise in Keisler's *Model Theory for Infinitary Logic: Logic with Countable Conjunctions
and Finite Quantifiers* (North Holland Publishing Company, 1971) says that $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$ has finite Robinson property if $\Psi$ in the above definition is countable, otherwise not. So it exists an uncountable $\Psi$ which is a counterexample to the property. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sigma =  \{P,(c_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1},f\}$, and let $\sigma' = \{P,(c_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1},(d_n)_{n<\omega}\}$. Here $P$ is a unary relation symbol, $f$ is a unary function symbol, and the $c_\alpha$ and $d_n$ are constant symbols. Then $\sigma\cap \sigma' = \{P,(c_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}\}$ Now define:
\begin{align*}\Psi &= \{P(c_\alpha)\land P(c_\beta)\land c_\alpha\neq c_\beta\mid \alpha<\beta<\omega_1\}\cup \{\exists x_1\dots\exists x_n(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \lnot  P(x_i)\land \bigwedge_{i\neq j} x_i\neq x_j)\mid n<\omega\}\\
\varphi &: (\forall  x\, (P(x)\rightarrow \lnot P(f(x)))\land (\forall x\forall y\, (f(x) = f(y)\rightarrow x = y))\\
\varphi' &: \forall x\, (\lnot P(x)\rightarrow \bigvee_{n<\omega} (x =  d_n))
\end{align*}

A model of $\Psi$ has $\omega_1$-many distinct elements named by constants and satisfying $P$ (as well as possibly other elements satisfying $P$), and infinitely many elements satisfying $\lnot P$. I claim that any two such models, say $M$ and $N$, are $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}(\sigma\cap \sigma')$-equivalent. Since any sentence of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ only mentions countably many symbols, it suffices to show that for any countable signature $\sigma^*\subseteq (\sigma\cap \sigma')$, the reducts $M|_{\sigma^*}$  and $N|_{\sigma^*}$ are $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}(\sigma^*)$-equivalent. Now $M|_{\sigma^*}$ and $N|_{\sigma^*}$ consist of countably-many distinct elements named by constants and satisfying $P$, infinitely many other elements satisfying $P$, and infinitely many elements satisfying $\lnot P$. By the infinite Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game,  $M|_{\sigma^*}$ and $N|_{\sigma^*}$ are $L_{\infty,\omega}(\sigma^*)$-equivalent.

A model of $\Psi\cup \{\varphi\}$ is a model $M$ of $\Psi$ together with an injective function $f\colon M\to M$ which maps $P$ into $\lnot P$. This is satisfiable, e.g. by taking $P$ to be $\omega_1$, with $c_\alpha =  \alpha$, taking $\lnot P$ to be a disjoint set $X$ of size $\aleph_1$, and taking $f = g\cup g^{-1}$, where $g$ is a bijection $X\to \omega_1$.

A model of $\Psi\cup \{\varphi'\}$ is a model $M$ of $\Psi$ such that every element of $\lnot P$ is named by some constant $d_n$. This is satisfiable, e.g. by taking $P$ to be $\omega_1$, with $c_\alpha =  \alpha$, taking $\lnot P$ to be a disjoint countably infinite set, each element of which is the interpretation of one of the constants $d_n$.

But $\Psi\cup \{\varphi,\varphi'\}$ is not satisfiable, because $\varphi$ forces $\lnot P$ to be uncountable, while $\varphi'$ forces $\lnot P$ to be countable.

Comment: I think it's an elegant counterexample, thanks. Just a question: how can the interpretaion of notP be a singleton in the second e.g.? I think it must be a countable set disjoint from omega, am I wrong?

Comment: @UmbertoCavasinni I never said the $d_n$ name distinct element. But of course there's also a model in which they are distinct, as you suggest.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm not referring to the $d_n$, but to the fact that $\lnot P$ cannot be $\{*\}$ because it has to be infinite. Otherwise I'm missing something.

Comment: @UmbertoCavasinni Oh, you're absolutely right, sorry! I'll fix it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again. Incidentally: I've found an unanswered question which refers to the same exercise in Keisler's book (I think I didn't find it before because I searched for Robinson 'property' but in that question the author referred to it as Robinson 'theorem').  Here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998969/robinson-consistency-theorem-for-l-omega-1-omega-logic?rq=1

Comment: @UmbertoCavasinni Thanks! Since that old question now has an answer here, I've marked it (the old question) as a duplicate.

Comment: let $\kappa$, $\lambda$ two infinite cardinals s.t. $\lambda<\kappa$ and $\kappa$ be regular; let $\mathfrak{A}\cong_{P, \lambda}\mathfrak{B}$ mean that there is a set of partial isomorphisms between $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ with back-and-forth enlarged from one-object-at-a-time to strictly-less-than-$\lambda$-objects-at-a-time (Karp thm is generalizable for this relation); if we substitute $\omega_1$ with $\kappa$ and $\omega$ with $\lambda$ in the previous example, do we obtain a counterexample for each infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa\lambda}$?

Comment: @UmbertoCavasinni yes, I believe so.